# QtThread: worker for I/O queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I'm trying to create my own worker thread for I/O operations. As far as I know the low-level management of the serial port is already done in a separate thread, but I want to put my code in another one to handle timeouts and other middleware stuff.

Here the *complete code* of my class. Please note it's my first attempt with Qt's multi-threading.

### EDIT

The code is updated without sub-classing `QThread`

```
#ifndef WORKERSERIAL_H
#define WORKERSERIAL_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>
#include <QQueue>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>

#include "myserial.h"

class WorkerSerial : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit WorkerSerial(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent)
    {
        m_serial = new MySerial(this);
        connect(m_serial, &MySerial::lineReceived, this, &WorkerSerial::serial_LineReceived);
        m_stop = false;
    }

    bool open(QString port, quint32 baudrate) { return m_serial->open(port, baudrate); }
    bool isOpen() { return m_serial->serial()->isOpen(); }
    QStringList ports() { return m_serial->ports(); }

private:
    MySerial *m_serial;
    QQueue<QString> m_queue;
    QMutex m_mutex;
    bool m_stop;

private slots:
    void serial_LineReceived(QByteArray line)
    {
        emit lineReceived(line);
    }

signals:
    void lineReceived(QByteArray line);

public slots:
    void close() { m_serial->close(); }
    void send(QString data) { m_mutex.lock(); m_queue.enqueue(data); m_mutex.unlock(); }
    void stop() { m_mutex.lock(); m_stop = true; m_mutex.unlock(); }
    void run() {
        forever {
            m_mutex.lock();
            if (m_stop)
            {
                qDebug() << "Closing...";
                QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(close()));
                while(m_serial->serial()->isOpen());
                m_mutex.unlock();
                return;
            }

            if (!m_queue.isEmpty())
            {
                QString data = m_queue.dequeue();
                qDebug() << m_serial->sendMessage(data.toLocal8Bit(), true);
            }
            m_mutex.unlock();
        }
    }

};

#endif // WORKERSERIAL_H
```

The `MySerial` class it's a convenient wrapper for `QSerialPort`. Here the relevant functions:

```
bool MySerial::open(QString port, quint32 baudrate) {
    m_serial->setPortName(port);
    if (!m_serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) return false;
    m_serial->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data7);
    m_serial->setParity(QSerialPort::EvenParity);
    m_serial->setStopBits(QSerialPort::TwoStop);
    m_serial->setBaudRate(baudrate);
    m_serial->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    return true;
}

QByteArray MySerial::sendMessage(QByteArray data) {
    m_serial->write(data);
    return data;
}
```

Finally, here how I start, use and close the worker:

```
QThread *workerThread = new QThread;
m_worker = new WorkerSerial;
m_worker->moveToThread(workerThread);
workerThread->start();
QTimer::singleShot(0, m_workerDMX, SLOT(run()));
// ...
m_worker->open("COM1", 250000));
// ...
m_worker->send("Hello World!");
// ...
m_worker->stop();
workerThread->quit();
workerThread->wait(1000);
// Here the application ends
```

This is the output:

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QSerialPort(0x19882160), parent's thread is QThread(0x187fe598), current thread is WorkerSerial(0x19d4c9b8)
[this error appears when it calls the SendMessage() function]
"Hello World!"
Closing...
QMutex: destroying locked mutex
QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running
[the two errors above are due the singleSlot() isn't executed and thus the serial won't close]
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
```

It seems clear I've messed up something! 
Would you help me to understand my mistakes?

Comment: It is not working as you expect because it is not serving Qt events on that thread. The BEST technique for threading: https://codethis.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/using-qthread-without-subclassing/ I thought of fixing your code there and there but decided the answer cannot be compact enough. OR you may take advantage of `QEventLoop`  instead of explicit loop for the thread you implemented. Also read of `QObject::moveToThread` and decide where your serial object lives (that is also on you). Also consider using `QMutexLocker` instead of explicit `QMutex::lock` and `unlock` but mind the scope

Comment: I adapted the code to the technique suggested in your link - there are very few lines to change. Anyway I get the same output. That means the problems are related to what I do inside the infinite loop, not to the threading itself.

Comment: AND with the object, like `QSerialPort` type you cannot freely call some of its methods on whichever thread. You want to call its methods especially producing messages objects with new (I guess according to an error) from one thread only and from the other thread you can signal to its slots or the slots on the thread where it lives to call those methods. Never spin the loop for waiting on the object like 'while(m_serial->serial()->isOpen());' when it has a signal for that.

Comment: Better post the adapted code then.

Comment: @Mark `QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(close()));` will never be executed, as you have overriden the `run()` function and did not create an event loop

Comment: @Mark make Qt do the work for you. Use signals/slots and queued connections and forgo the mutex and the forever loop.

Comment: @InnocentBystander I did that way reading the Qt's docs... please would you provide an example to use queued connections and to forget the mutex/foverer loop?

Comment: @AlexanderVX for calling slots I have to use the QTimer::singleShot() function, right? And I used a loop because I'm in a different thread! I mean, it's just an example, but I thought it's possible because it should not hang the UI.

Comment: @Mark, that is second favorite technique and all signals will be working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29449561/qeventloop-proper-usage Your loop needs something like `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` but then you will have more questions and that raises more questions with checking on loop condition.

Comment: @Mark I'll try to come up with an answer. But first lemme aks you sum': what's the purpose of the queue in your example?

Comment: @InnocentBystander From my application I will append a lot of messages to be sent over the serial line. The worker has to transmit one by one, waiting some time before signaling a timeout (i.e. the receiver has not answered) and go ahead with the next one.

Answer (score 2):

Here is (an incomplete) implementation, which should give you an idea of how to simplify your code. Some additional notes are below:

```
class WorkerSerial : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit WorkerSerial(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent)
    {
        // no need for slot -- connect directly to our signal
        connect(&m_serial, &MySerial::lineReceived, this, &WorkerSerial::lineReceived);
    }

    bool open(QString port, quint32 baudrate) { return m_serial.open(port, baudrate); }
    bool isOpen() { return m_serial.serial().isOpen(); }
    QStringList ports() { return m_serial.ports(); }

private:
    // doesn't need to be a pointer
    MySerial m_serial;

signals:
    void lineReceived(const QByteArray& line);

public slots:
    void close() { m_serial.close(); }

    void send(const QByteArray& data)
    {
        // "lengthy" function call
        qDebug() << m_serial.sendMessage(data, true);
    }
};

class Sender : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    void send(const QByteArray& data) { emit sig_send(data); }

signals:
    void sig_send(const QByteArray& data);
}

...

WorkerSerial m_worker;
m_worker.open("COM1", 250000));

QThread m_thread;
m_worker.moveToThread(&m_thread);
m_thread.start();

Sender m_sender;
QObject::connect(&m_sender, &Sender::sig_send, &m_worker, &WorkerSerial::send, Qt::QueuedConnection);

m_sender.send("Hello World!");

m_thread.quit();
m_thread.wait();

m_worker.close();
```

Additional notes:

1. I've added a `Sender` class that queues calls to `WorkerSerial::send()` on a different thread. If you have a signal in your code, which triggers calls to `WorkerSerial::send()` you don't need this class.
2. Once you move `m_worker` to another thread, it is *unsafe* to access any of its methods, unless (a) they are guaranteed to be thread-safe; or (b) you serialize (protect) access to `m_serial` with a mutex.

Comment: As far I as I undestand, my "queue" is replaced by the `Qt::QueuedConnection" mechanism, which queues new signals until the slot is executed for each one. This could work, but has some drawbacks: 1. I cannot know (can I?) the current queue size, 2. I cannot rely on the order (https://forum.qt.io/topic/51291/solved-are-signals-handled-in-the-order-sent-c-to-qml/5), 3. I need to "block" the slot send() waiting for incoming data or timeout.

Comment: @Mark, 1. Correct. You can probably add a counter inside `Sender::send` if you need to know the size of the queue. 2. You are firing signals from the same thread. There is no reason why they would end up out of order. You can probably make a small test cast to prove/disprove that. 3. Yes we can :) I couldn't tell from your snippets how the responses are handled, so I didn't address that

Comment: @Mark according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16189542/4358570) you are safe to assume the signals will be executed in order

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: this is not a fully working solution (yet). But I think it's better to post it as an answer than add another piece of code in the original question.

I managed to a different approach. Perhaps it looks weird... but it should have some advantages:

- it guarantees the order of the messages to be transmitted
- using a `QQueue` I can know the queue size or other information about
- the "variable shadowing" mechanism should allow to safely communicate with the thread

Here the code, below the two last issues:

```
#ifndef WORKERSERIAL_H
#define WORKERSERIAL_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>
#include <QQueue>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QDebug>

#include "myserial.h"

class WorkerSerial : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit WorkerSerial(QObject *parent = 0, int timeout = 0) : QThread(parent), timeout(timeout)
    {
        quit = false;
        command = None;
    }

    ~WorkerSerial()
    {
        mutex.lock();
        quit = true;
        mutex.unlock();
        wait();
    }

    void open(QString port, quint32 baudrate)
    {
        mutex.lock();
        this->port = port;
        this->baudrate = baudrate;
        command = Open;
        mutex.unlock();
    }

    void close()
    {
        mutex.lock();
        command = Close;
        mutex.unlock();
    }

    void stop()
    {
        mutex.lock();
        command = Quit;
        mutex.unlock();
    }

private:
    enum Commands
    {
        None,
        Open,
        Close,
        Quit
    };

    QQueue<QString> m_queue;
    QMutex mutex;
    int timeout;
    int command;
    QString port;
    int baudrate;
    QString request;
    bool quit;

signals:
    void portStateChanged(bool isOpen);
    void lineReceived(QByteArray line);

public slots:
    void send(QString data)
    {
        mutex.lock();
        m_queue.enqueue(data);
        mutex.unlock();
    }

    void run()
    {
        MySerial serial;
        QString _port;
        int _baudrate;
        int _timeout;
        QString _request = "";
        int _command = None;

        connect(&serial, &MySerial::lineReceived, this, &WorkerSerial::lineReceived);
        mutex.lock();
        _timeout = timeout;
        mutex.unlock();

        forever {
            mutex.lock();
            _command = command;         
            command = None;
            if (!m_queue.isEmpty()) _request = m_queue.dequeue();
            mutex.unlock();

            switch (_command) {
            case Open:
                mutex.lock();
                _port = port;
                _baudrate = baudrate;
                mutex.unlock();
                if (serial.open(_port, _baudrate)) emit portStateChanged(true);
                else portStateChanged(false);
                break;

            case Close:
                serial.close();
                emit portStateChanged(serial.serial()->isOpen());
                break;

            case Quit:
                serial.close();
                return;
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }

            if (!_request.isEmpty())
            {
                qDebug() << serial.sendMessage(_request.toLocal8Bit(), true);
                _request = "";
            }
            msleep(1);
        }
    }

};

#endif // WORKERSERIAL_H
```

Here how to use it:

```
WorkerSerial *worker = new WorkerSerial(this);
connect(worker , &WorkerSerial::lineReceived, this, &MainWindow::lineReceived);
connect(worker , &WorkerSerial::portStateChanged, this, &MainWindow::portStateChanged);
worker->start();
// ..
worker->open("COM2", 250000);
worker->send("Hello World");
// ..
worker->stop();
worker->wait(1000);
```

It "works" but there are two main issues:

1. the serialport is opened but the data are not actually transmitted. The `MySerial` class is working because if I do the following, bypassing the `WorkerSerial`:

---

```
MySerial serial;
serial.open("COM2", 250000);
serial.sendMessage("Hello World!", true);
```

the data is sent! Hence there is still something wrong in my `WorkerSerial`.

2. due to the `forever` loop, I need to insert a small delay, otherwise the CPU will run up to 100% doing nothing.

Comment: If you are going this route, I would suggest adding [`QWaitCondition`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwaitcondition.html#details) to your `WorkerSerial` class to avoid useless iterations inside `forever` loop and save some trees :P